# In Nodejs, how to extract just domain.com from url?

Tags: node.js

Given urls like these

```
www.yahoo.com
support.abc.com/whatever?a=1
clear.com
biz.co.uk/how
```

How do I get

```
yahoo.com
abc.com
clear.com
biz.co.uk
```

Url.parse.hostname returns url including subdomain and how would nodejs or browser know biz is domain name not subdomain

Answer (score 2):

> and how would nodejs or browser know biz is domain name not subdomain

Using the [Public Suffix List](https://publicsuffix.org/) information, for example through a library like [tldjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tldjs) for JavaScript.

Comment: extending on @hobbs answer to point directly to the [getDomain](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tldjs#getdomain) function: ```const { getDomain } = require('tldjs'); const domain = getDomain('foo.google.com');```